# "Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 and Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1- connect timed out"

Tags: eclipse, maven

New Maven Project is created in eclipse with. But Pom.xml shows some error.

> "Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6"

and

> "org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to
>   central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out"

How to solve it.

Please Note: project do get build from Command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In This Maven project has two error. One is
"**org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out**"

**Solution**: Is this due to connectivity issue, From your system the Meven repository is not reachable or you do not have right to access or download repository.
For this 1st check your proxy setting in setting.xml of maven. If Setting is right then you domain blocked the repo site.

Then down load plugins via allowed mirror for you domain.

Second is

**"Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6"**

**Solution**: This might be your eclipse M2e connector installed in bundle. Update your connector. I have solved by **"M2E connector for the Eclipse JDT Compiler"**.